# Difference between \href{xxx.pdf}{} and \href{run:xxx.pdf}{}

Tags: hyperref, links, hyperlink, href

What are the differences between these two types of links?

```
    \href{xxx.pdf}{My PDF}
\href{run:xxx.pdf}{run:My PDF}
```

Both open the same file in Acrobat (but at different zoom levels?). However, in TeXShop, only the `run:` version opens the file.  I have always used the second style, but as both seem to be valid, I am wondering if I need to change things?

### Questions:

1. What are the difference between these two types of links?
2. When should I use the first style versus the second style?

### Notes:

- At this time, I am *only* asking regarding opening *external* pdf files.  Having answers regarding non-pdf files (in case there are different issues involved) if fine too, as that may be useful to others.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document} 
        \href{xxx.pdf}{My PDF}\quad
    \href{run:xxx.pdf}{run:My PDF}
\end{document}
```

Comment: run is intended to launch an application rather than open a file, I think it just happens to work if you give it a pdf file that it opens it in your default pdf viewer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly modified version of your document:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\href{xxx.pdf}{My PDF}
\href{run:xxx.pdf}{run:My PDF}
\end{document}
```

You get an uncompressed PDF and therefore a readable PDF (by opening it directly in your favorite editor).

1. The first link is coded as a `GoToR` action (a remote go-to action) similar to an ordinary go-to action but jumps to a destination in another PDF file instead of the current file:

   ```
   /Subtype/Link/A<</F(xxx.pdf)/S/GoToR/D[0/Fit]>>
   ```
2. The second link is coded as a `Launch` action (to launch an external application):

   ```
   /Subtype/Link/A<</F(xxx.pdf)/S/Launch>>
   ```

See [section 12.6.4.1, p.417-418, Document management — Portable document format — Part 1:
PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=425)